# Search filter in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement the search filter for the following application using angularjs. But it's not working as intended. I am new to this so I am not sure what I've done wrong here. Can someone help?

Here is my code so far:-

**index.html file :**

```
<html>    
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="Controller/app.js"></script>
      <script src="Controller/storage.js"></script>    
   </head>
   <body ng-app="kfgPm">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
        <form name="kfgPmForm" ng-submit="submitForm(kfgPmForm.$valid)" novalidate>

            <div class="col-sm-12" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <label for="projectID" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Project ID: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="projectID" required ng-model="itm.projectID">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <label for="projectName" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Project Name: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="projectName" required ng-model="itm.projectName">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <label for="projectOwner" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Project Owner: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="projectOwner" required ng-model="itm.projectOwner">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group  col-sm-6">
                    <label for="keyStake" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Key Stakeholders: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyStake" required ng-model="itm.keyStake">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <label for="prepBy" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Prepared By: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prepBy" required ng-model="itm.prepBy">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group  col-sm-6">
                    <label for="reqDate" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Requested Date: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reqDate" required ng-model="itm.reqDate">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12" class="form-group" ng-submit="submitDetails()" role="form">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6" class="input-group mb-3">
                    <label for="inputGroupSelect01" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Status: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select name="status" class="form-control custom-select" ng-options="user.option for user in arrlist" required ng-model="user.itm.status">
                                        <option value="">Select..</option>
                                       </select>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <label for="dept" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Department: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dept" required ng-model="itm.dept">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-sm-12" class="form-group purple-border">

                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label for="projSummary">Project Summary: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="projSummary" required ng-model="itm.projSummary" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>


        <div class="form-row text-center">
            <div class="col-12">
                <button ng-disabled="kfgPmForm.$invalid" ng-click="update(itm)" class="btn btn-info">SUBMIT</button>
                <div><br></div>
                </form>
                <div><br></div>


                <div class="col-sm-12" class="form-horizontal">
                    <label for="search" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Search: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input ng-model="searchText" class="form-control" ng-keyup="filterFunc()">
                        <div><br></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="results">

                    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center">
                        <thead class="thead-light">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Project ID</th>
                                <th>Project Name</th>
                                <th>Project Owner</th>
                                <th>Key Stakeholders</th>
                                <th>Prepared By</th>
                                <th>Requested Date</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Department</th>
                                <th>Project Summary</th>
                                <th>ACTIONS</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <tr ng-repeat="itm in master | filter: itm.search">
                                <td><span ng-hide="editMode">{{itm.projectID}}</span>
                                    <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="itm.projectID" />
                                </td>
                                <td><span ng-hide="editMode">{{itm.projectName}}</span>
                                    <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="itm.projectName" />
                                </td>
                                <td><span ng-hide="editMode">{{itm.projectOwner}}</span>
                                    <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="itm.projectOwner" />
                                </td>
                                <td><span ng-hide="editMode">{{itm.keyStake}}</span>
                                    <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="itm.keyStake" />
                                </td>
                                <td><span ng-hide="editMode">{{itm.prepBy}}</span>
                                    <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="itm.prepBy" />
                                </td>

                                <td><span ng-hide="editMode">{{itm.reqDate}}</span>
                                    <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="itm.reqDate" />
                                </td>
                                <td><span ng-hide="editMode">{{itm.status.option}}</span>
                                    <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="itm.status" />
                                </td>
                                <td><span ng-hide="editMode">{{itm.dept}}</span>
                                    <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="itm.dept" />
                                </td>
                                <td><span ng-hide="editMode">{{itm.projSummary}}</span>
                                    <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="itm.projSummary" />
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <button ng-click="EditProject(itm)" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                                    <button ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="removeItem($index)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
            <br>
        </div>


</body>

</html>
```

**This is my app.js file:**

```
var isHtml5Compatible = document.createElement('canvas').getContext != undefined;
if (isHtml5Compatible) {
    initiateLocalStorage();
}

function initiateLocalStorage() {
    var app = angular.module('kfgPm', ['storageService']);    
    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'getLocalStorage', function($scope, getLocalStorage) {    
        $scope.EditProject = EditProject;
        $scope.master = getLocalStorage.getData();

        $scope.master = [];

        $scope.update = function() {
            var IsNew = true; //if the data entered in the field is new 
            angular.forEach($scope.master, function(LItem, key) {
                if (LItem.projectID == $scope.itm.projectID) { //if the new project ID equals old project ID
                    IsNew = false; //data entered is to be edited
                    LItem.projectID = $scope.itm.projectID;
                    LItem.projectName = $scope.itm.projectName;
                    LItem.projectOwner = $scope.itm.projectOwner;
                    LItem.keyStake = $scope.itm.keyStake;
                    LItem.prepBy = $scope.itm.prepBy;
                    LItem.reqDate = $scope.itm.reqDate;
                    LItem.status = $scope.itm.status;
                    LItem.dept = $scope.itm.dept;
                    LItem.projSummary = $scope.itm.projSummary;                       
                }
            });
            if (IsNew) { //if new data
                $scope.master.push({ //add to the fields
                    'projectID': $scope.itm.projectID,
                    'projectName': $scope.itm.projectName,
                    'projectOwner': $scope.itm.projectOwner,
                    'keyStake': $scope.itm.keyStake,
                    'prepBy': $scope.itm.prepBy,
                    'reqDate': $scope.itm.reqDate,
                    'status': $scope.itm.status,
                    'dept': $scope.itm.dept,
                    'projSummary': $scope.itm.projSummary,                        
                });
            }
            getLocalStorage.update($scope.master);
            $scope.itm.projectID = '';
            $scope.itm.projectName = '';
            $scope.itm.projectOwner = '';
            $scope.itm.keyStake = '';
            $scope.itm.prepBy = '';
            $scope.itm.reqDate = '';
            $scope.itm.status = '';
            $scope.itm.dept = '';
            $scope.itm.projSummary = '';              
        },

        $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
            console.log(index);
            $scope.master.splice(index, 1)
            getLocalStorage.update($scope.master);
        },

        $scope.editItem = function(index) {
            getLocalStorage.update($scope.master);
            $scope.editing = $scope.master.indexOf(index);
        }

        function EditProject(pItem) { //if edit is clicked the data is replaced in respective fields
            $scope.itm.projectID = pItem.projectID;
            $scope.itm.projectName = pItem.projectName;
            $scope.itm.projectOwner = pItem.projectOwner;
            $scope.itm.keyStake = pItem.keyStake;
            $scope.itm.prepBy = pItem.prepBy;
            $scope.itm.reqDate = pItem.reqDate;
            $scope.itm.status = pItem.status;
            $scope.itm.dept = pItem.dept;
            $scope.itm.projSummary = pItem.projSummary;
            console.log(pItem);
        }

        $scope.arrlist = [{
            "id": 1,
            "option": "One"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "option": "Two"
        }];
        $scope.userselected = $scope.arrlist[1];               
        $scope.LItem = angular.copy($scope.update);

        $scope.filterFunc = function() {
            $scope.LItem = $filter('filter')($scope.update, { $: $scope.searchText });
        }
        $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
            if (isValid) {
                alert('Submitted Successfully');
            }
        };
    }]);    
}
```

I am trying to implement the search for all columns such that when I type something in the search text field, it should return only the row with those searched terms and the rest of the rows would be hidden in the table.

Comment: **Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem.** If your question isn’t about a HTML errors, ensure that there are no HTML errors. **Describe the problem.** "it's not working as intended" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. **Minimal** Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem,
The more code there is to go through, the less likely people can find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To start, I see the following problems:

```
<body ng-app="kfgPm">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
    <form name="kfgPmForm" ng-submit="submitForm(kfgPmForm.$valid)" novalidate>

        <!-- duplicate class attribute -->
        <div class="col-sm-12" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

            <!-- end tag seen too early -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

1. Duplicate class attribute -- the second one will be ignored
2. End tag seen too early - the scope of the controller will be limited

These two errors alone will cause the app to fail.

Also `angular.js` and `bootstrap.js` do not play well together. They do not co-ordinate their manipulation of the DOM.

Comment: I am sorry it was not a duplicate class attribute, it was an editing mistake. I have corrected my code now. Can you please check now? I think there's some mistake in the app.js file but I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Those are not the only errors in the HTML. To see more, look at the code editor in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/RcrkLZthGTqa7g9gGY1K?p=preview).